# Setting Ember Model to an Ember Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ember.js

I have a client class which has many requests:

```
var attr = DS.attr;
var hasMany = DS.hasMany;
App.Client = DS.Model.extend({
  requests:hasMany("request",{async:true})
});
```

Then in my ClientRoute, I wish to load a client and set it to my model.

```
App.ClientRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model:function(params){
      return this.store.find("client",params.client_id)
  }
})
```

This kind of works, except that the requests attribute of the model is undefined(I inspected it in the console to be sure).

However, if I explicity push the client into the store, the requests attribute works properly:

```
App.ClientRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model:function(params){
      var route=this;
      return $.getJSON("/clients/"+params.client_id).then(function(client){
          return route.store.push("client",client.client)

      })
  }
})
```

Why is this happening?  I thought the first example was the accepted way to do this kind of thing?  Note, my backend is simply return the following (in JSON):

```
{client:{id:1,requests:[1,2]}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the RESTAdapter then the format you're using is correct:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/566/edit

Comment: yes, the first one, In the example provided I'm using your same json and it's working.